# Why is my use of 'fgets' causing a struct pointer's char array property to populate?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm compiling this on a Linux 64bit machine.

Running `gcc struct-string-gates.c && ./a.out` provides the following, unexpected output:
`Val: '0', Name: '123 -> x'`

However, if I comment out the `while(fgets..` loop, I get the following, expected output: `Val: '0', Name: ''`

Am I causing an overflow somewhere?

**gates.txt (UTF-8)**

```
123 -> x
```

**struct-string-gates.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME "gates.txt"
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 100

#define VAR_NAME_LEN 5

char **readLines(char *fileName) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *buff = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN * sizeof(char));
    
    // Including the following while loop seems to cause the issue
    while (fgets(buff, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL) {
        // Empty fn
    }

    char **lines = NULL;
    fclose(fp);
    free(buff);
    return lines;
}

typedef struct Gate Gate;
struct Gate {
    char name[VAR_NAME_LEN];
    int output;
};

int main() {
    char **lines= readLines(FILE_NAME);

    Gate *newGate = malloc(sizeof(Gate));
    printf("Val: '%d', Name: '%s'\n", newGate->output, newGate->name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: UB1 and UB2 appear to be different in your specific case. They might be equal, both expected or both unexpected... they might be different with both unexpected... nasal daemons might start oozing out your nostrils.

Comment: You don't initialise the values of your struct. So it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your structure `*newGate` is uninitialized, so the `printf` will show the data that were stored at the same memory location before.

Comment: `char **lines = NULL;
    fclose(fp);
    free(buff);
    return lines;` <<-- so, you are returning NULL.

Comment: @wildplasser yes, I've trimmed down the file for narrowing down the cause.

Comment: @TornaxO7 @Bodo I guess that is it! After fixing that, all is good. I guess I assumed they would have default, but I was mistaken. I'll maybe just make a `createGate` function that initializes values.

Comment: You can look, if you have an buffer overflow by adding the given compile-flags. Try to compile it with `gcc -fsanitize=address -g struct-string-gates.c` and run it with valgrind.